# How to add image in react by using parcel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, parceljs

I have been trying to add image in `react`. I'm not using `webpack`, I'm using `parceljs`. Also using `typescript` I have try:

`import image from path/to/image.png`
`<img src={image} />`

inside react component:

try: `<img src="path/to/image.png" />`

try: `<img src={"path/to/image.png"} />`

Still, doesn't work.

code look sort of like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const componentName = () => (
  <div>
     <img src="path/to/image.png" />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Parcel supports importing asset files with `import` syntax. But the path must be a string.
`import image from 'path/to/image.png'`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to do it like this

```
import image from 'path/to/image.png';
```

And then inside your react `JSX` follow below code:

```
<img src={image} />
```

Comment: For Parcel 2 use `import image from 'url:path/to/image.png';` . Source: https://v2.parceljs.org/recipes/image/

Answer (score 5):

It is no different between `<img src="path/to/image.png"/>` and `<img src={"path/to/image.png"}/>`, you should `import` your image and then use it like a `JavaScript` object, see below:

```
import somePhoto from 'path/to/image.png';
```

You don't attend to `'path/to/image.png';` and wrote it like nothing. input your path in a quotation mark. Then inside your `react` `JSX` code write your `img` tag like below:

```
<img src={somePhoto} />
```

There are more different ways. in other `react` projects we use another server to load the images. but the specific images for application should be like above.

Answer (score 0):

```
use static image with parcel problem solved......
```

I have the same problem but you can fix it using parcel-plugin-static-files-copy package: parcel-plugin-static-files-copy. Then install by using this command npm i parcel-plugin-static-files-copy , then add this to your .parcelrc plagin

{
"extends": "@parcel/config-default",
"resolvers": ["@parcel/resolver-glob", "..."]
}
Once enabled, you can import multiple files using a specifier like ./files/*.png. This returns an object with keys corresponding to the files names.

import * as images from './img/types/*.svg';

use--- i have images folder inside static(root) folder

i have 16 image in this images folder now i can use as their name

Answer (score 0):

As of Parcel 2, you can include images using `URL`. See https://parceljs.org/recipes/react/#images

```js
const logo = new URL('logo.svg', import.meta.url);

export function Logo() {
  return <img src={logo} alt="logo" />;
}
```

Here's an example project layout for using js+images:

```
$ tree -I node_modules/ -I dist
.
├── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── img
    │   └── logo.png
    └── js
        └── index.js
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="src/js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

src/js/index.js:

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'


function App() {
  const logo = new URL('/src/img/logo.png', import.meta.url)

  return <div>
    <h1>My App</h1>
    <img src={logo} alt='logo'/>
  </div>
}

const domNode = document.getElementById('root')
const root = createRoot(domNode)
root.render(<App/>)
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me
`use this:`

```
<img className="res-logo" src={require('/images/download.jpg')}/>
```

if your images are in a folder then install 2 packages through the terminal.

```
npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader
npm file loader: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader
```